# Prove that $(S1\cup S2)-(S1\cap \neg S2) = S2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I need to prove

i) $(S1\cup S2)-(S1\cap \neg S2) \subseteq S2$

ii) $S2 \subseteq (S1\cup S2)-(S1\cap\neg S2)$

Proof of i)

Suppose $\exists x\in(S1 \cup S2) - (S1 \cap \neg S2)$ such that $x\notin S2$. So, $x\in (S1 \cup S2)$ and $x\in (\neg S1 \cup S2)$. We also supposed $x\in \neg S2$.

I don't have any idea about how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to use elementary Set identities (which perfectly correspond to boolean logic principles):

$$(S1 \cup S2) - (S1 \cap S2') = (S1 \cup S2) \cap (S1 \cap S2')' = (S1 \cup S2) \cap (S1' \cup S2) = S2$$

But if not:

If $x\in(S1 \cup S2) - (S1 \cap \neg S2)$, then $x\in(S1 \cup S2)$ but $x \not \in (S1 \cap \neg S2)$. So, if you assume $x \not  \in S2$, then given that $x\in(S1 \cup S2)$, it must be the case that $x \in S1$.  But then $x \in (S1 \cap \neg S2)$, which contradicts $x \not \in (S1 \cap \neg S2)$. So, the assumption is false, and hence $x \in S2$

Comment: How come x belongs to S1? x can either belong to S1 or S2 given that $x \in S1 \cap S2$

Comment: Just given that $x \in S1 \cup S2$, yes ... but I also assumed that $x \not \in S2$ as part of a proof by contradiction.

Comment: thanks that makes total sense!